# Как сделать GET fetch запрос в PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fetch

Делаю FETCH запрос из js в файл, все проходит но почему-то если я пытаюсь гет вывести после 4-5 строчке, он не выводится при этом сейчас он на 3 строчке и все отрабатывает. В чем может быть проблема?
При этом если отправляю запрос через jQuery - $('#feedback-load').load все работает, в network preview все отображается.
Как только делаю

```
var formHeaderEntry = fetch('/ajx/feedback-load.php?clinic=' + clinic + '&sid=' + sid + '&ibid=' + ibid + '&ecode=' + ecode + '&scode=' + scode, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/text; charset=UTF-8',
                    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
                }
            });
```

network preview приходит пустой, а мне нужен именно запрос без использования jq
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");
    \Bitrix\Main\Loader::includeModule('iblock');

    //global $ecode, $scode, $sid, $ibid;

    $ecode = htmlspecialchars($_GET['ecode']);
    $scode = htmlspecialchars($_GET['scode']);
    $sid = htmlspecialchars($_GET['sid']);
    $ibid = htmlspecialchars($_GET['ibid']);

    $elAddr = array();

    if (!empty($sid)) {

        $rsResult = CIBlockSection::GetList(array("SORT" => "ASC"), array("IBLOCK_ID" => 5, "ID" => $sid), false, $arSelect = array("UF_*"));
        if ($arSection = $rsResult->GetNext()) {
            $elAddr = $arSection['UF_CLINICS'];
        }
    }

    if (empty($ibid)) {
        $ibid = 5;
    }

    if (!empty($scode)) {
        if ($scode == 'na-michurinskom' || $scode == 'mich' || $scode == 'v-klinike-na-michurinskom-prospekte-d-6-str-4') {
            $elAddr[] = 73;
        }

        if ($scode == 'na-zoologicheskoy' || $scode == 'zoo' || $scode == 'v-klinike-na-zoologicheskoy-ulitse-d-22') {
            $elAddr[] = 38;
        }
    }


    if (!empty($ecode)) {


        $arSelect = array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM", "PROPERTY_*"); //IBLOCK_ID и ID обязательно должны быть указаны, см. описание arSelectFields выше
        $arFilter = array("IBLOCK_ID" => $ibid, "CODE" => $ecode, "ACTIVE" => "Y");
        $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(array(), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
        while ($ob = $res->GetNextElement()) {
            $props = $ob->GetProperties();


            $elAddr = $props['OTDEL']['VALUE'];

            if (empty($elAddr)) {
                $elAddr = $props['CLINICS']['VALUE'];
            }

            if (empty($elAddr)) {
                $elAddr = $props['CLINIC']['VALUE'];
            }
        }
    }
    if (!empty($_GET['clinic'])) {
        $elAddr[] = htmlspecialchars($_GET['clinic']);
    }

?>
    <div class="consult big">
        <div class="container container-form">
            <div class="consult_title">
                <b class="to-title"></b>

                <div class="close-overlay"></div>
            </div>
            <form class="feedback-form zform" name="feedback-form" id="calltracking_4">
                <input type="hidden" name="THEME" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" id="pagenamef" name="PAGE_NAME" value=''>
                <input type="hidden" id="pageurlf" name="PAGE_URL" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="TYPE" id="type" value="Z">
                <div class="consult_row">
                    <?
                    $arSelect = array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM", "PROPERTY_*"); //IBLOCK_ID и ID обязательно должны быть указаны, см. описание arSelectFields выше
                    $arFilter = array("IBLOCK_ID" => 10, "ACTIVE" => "Y");
                    $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(array("SORT" => "ASC"), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
                    while ($ob = $res->GetNextElement()) {
                        $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
                        $arFields['PROPERTIES'] = $ob->GetProperties();

                        if (!empty($elAddr)) {
                            if (!in_array($arFields['ID'], $elAddr)) {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    ?> <div class="input z-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="oradio<?= $arFields['ID'] ?>" name="CLINIC" value="<?= $arFields['ID'] ?>" /> <label for="oradio<?= $arFields['ID'] ?>"><?= str_replace("Москва,", "", strip_tags($arFields['PROPERTIES']['ADRESS']['~VALUE'])); ?></label>
                        </div>
                    <? } ?>
                </div>
                <div class="consult_row">
                    <div class="input">
                        <div class="req" style="width: 100%"><input type="text" name="NAME" placeholder="Имя"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <div class="req" style="width: 100%"><input type="text" name="PHONE" placeholder="Телефон"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="req" style="width: 100%"><textarea name="MESSAGE" id="message" class="req" placeholder="<? if ($GLOBALS["APPLICATION"]->GetCurPage(false) == '/quotes/') : ?>Текст отзыва<? else : ?>Комментарии<? endif; ?>"></textarea></div>
                <div style="width: 100%"></div>
                <div class="errors"></div>
                <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
                <p>Нажимая кнопку "<b>Отправить</b>" вы соглашаетесь на <a href="/agreement/" target="_blank" title="Согласие на обработку персональных данных">обработку персональных данных</a>.</p>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="container container-thanks">
            <div class="consult_title">
                <b>Спасибо</b>

                <div class="close-overlay"></div>
            </div>
            <form class="feedback-form">
                <p>Спасибо, ваше сообщение отправлено!</p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: потому что fetch это асинхронная операция присваивая результат запроса просто переменной ничего не будет. Читайте что такое промисы и как с ними работать, в данном случае с fetch

Comment: Какой-то бред, "Делаю FETCH запрос из js в файл, все проходит но почему-то если я пытаюсь гет вывести после 4-5 строчке, он не выводится при этом сейчас он на 3 строчке и все отрабатывает.", причем тут асинхронность? Если в пхп приходит запрос и он отдает ответ, при этом если вывести вар дамп/echo ниже модулей подключения, уже не выводится

Comment: раз падает если ставить после 4-й строки, то значит проблема в этих двух строках. Покажите чему равна переменная DOCUMENT_ROOT (сделайте дамп в 3 строке), не пустая ли она. Далее при отправке запросов в тело и шапку запроса могут подставляться определённые параметры которые требует битрикс для правильного подключения модулей, например iblock. Посмотрите какие хедеры и тело запроса отправляется при использовании .load а чего не хватает при использовании fetch